# How do I access the Access Token from the Spotify web API in Go?

Tags: go, pointers, spotify, go-fiber

I need to access my access token from the `CompleteAuth` function, so I can use in my other endpoints.

```golang
func CompleteAuth(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tok, err := auth.Token(r.Context(), state, r)

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Couldn't get token", http.StatusForbidden)
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if st := r.FormValue("state"); st != state {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        log.Fatalf("State mismatch: %s != %s\n", st, state)
    }

    // use the token to get an authenticated client
    client := spotify.New(auth.Client(r.Context(), tok))
    fmt.Println("Access Token:" + tok.AccessToken + "\n")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Login Completed!")
    ch <- client
}

func RegHand(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("Got request for:", r.URL.String())

    url := auth.AuthURL(state)
    fmt.Println("Please log in to Spotify by visiting the following page in your browser:", url+"\n")

    // wait for auth to complete
    client := <-ch

    // use the client to make calls that require authorization
    user, err := client.CurrentUser(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("You are logged in as:", user.ID)
}
```

I've tried to create a pointer to the `tok` variable, but it does not seem to work.
Would it be possible to create a custom interface that contains the access token that is generated by the `completeAuth` function?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom interface to store the access token generated by the CompleteAuth function and then use that interface in your other endpoints. Here's an example of how you can do this:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/zmb3/spotify"
)

// AccessTokenProvider defines the interface for accessing the access token.
type AccessTokenProvider interface {
    AccessToken() string
}

// TokenHolder implements the AccessTokenProvider interface.
type TokenHolder struct {
    Token *spotify.Token
}

// AccessToken returns the access token.
func (th *TokenHolder) AccessToken() string {
    return th.Token.AccessToken
}

var accessTokenProvider AccessTokenProvider

func CompleteAuth(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    tok, err := auth.Token(r.Context(), state, r)

    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, "Couldn't get token", http.StatusForbidden)
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    if st := r.FormValue("state"); st != state {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        log.Fatalf("State mismatch: %s != %s\n", st, state)
    }

    // Set the access token provider
    accessTokenProvider = &TokenHolder{Token: tok}

    // use the token to get an authenticated client
    client := spotify.New(auth.Client(r.Context(), tok))
    fmt.Println("Access Token:" + tok.AccessToken + "\n")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Login Completed!")
    ch <- client
}

func RegHand(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    log.Println("Got request for:", r.URL.String())

    url := auth.AuthURL(state)
    fmt.Println("Please log in to Spotify by visiting the following page in your browser:", url+"\n")

    // wait for auth to complete
    client := <-ch

    // use the client to make calls that require authorization
    user, err := client.CurrentUser(context.Background())
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println("You are logged in as:", user.ID)

    // Now you can use the access token provider to access the token
    accessToken := accessTokenProvider.AccessToken()
    fmt.Println("Access Token from RegHand:", accessToken)
}

func main() {
    // Your main function implementation here
}
```

I've created an AccessTokenProvider interface with a method AccessToken() that returns the access token.

Then, defined a TokenHolder struct that implements this interface and holds the access token generated by the CompleteAuth function.

Finally, I've set the accessTokenProvider variable to point to an instance of TokenHolder when the access token is generated in the CompleteAuth function.

You can then use accessTokenProvider to access the access token in your RegHand function or any other part of your code.

For example:

```
func SomeOtherFunction() {
    // Access the access token using the accessTokenProvider
    accessToken := accessTokenProvider.AccessToken()
    fmt.Println("Access Token from SomeOtherFunction:", accessToken)
}
```